# Local Data Store parse.com android

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse.com android api, and whenever there is internet, it works fine but I can't fetch it when my device is offline.
Here is the code:

```
private void initializeparseData() {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID",
            "CLIENT_ID");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);       
}
```

I'm adding to the dataStore like this :

```
private void parseData()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("CLASS_NAME");
    query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("objects", new DeleteCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("objects",objects);
            }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

And this is how I fetch it :

```
enter code here
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("CLASS_NAME");
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.fromPin("objects");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
          public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
              Log.i("shant", "PARSE GET: "+objects+" SIZE: "+objects.size());

         }
   });
```

And still I have this error! :

```
Method requires Local Datastore.Please refer to `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)`.
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

try this.
Just pin all objects without passing parameters .
ParseObject.pinAllInBackground( );

for fetching on local side
perform same query but  add
query.fromLocalDatastore();to query. 
dont include .frompin..

Answer (score 0):

You have to Set enabled Parse local data Store after 
APP_ID end APP_KEY